# Woocommerce бесплатная доставка

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как в woocommerce сделать бесплатную доставку не отдельным пунктом, а обнуляя стоимость имеющимся способам доставки?

Бесплатная доставка при сумме заказа от определенной суммы. 
Выводить её отдельным пунктом неудобно, потому что от вариантов доставки зависит вывод способов оплаты.

Answer (score 0):

Решила проблему. Сделала три способа бесплатной доставки, в functions.php добавила:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'conditionally_hide_shipping_methods', 100, 2 );
            function conditionally_hide_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
                // HERE yours 2nd flat rate "Express Shipping" (that you never hide) in the array:
                $flat_rates_express = array( 'flat_rate:5', 'flat_rate:12', 'flat_rate:14' );

                $free = $flat2 = array();
                foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
                    // Updated Here To 
                    if ( in_array( $rate->id, $flat_rates_express ) )
                        $flat2[ $rate_key ] = $rate;
                    if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id )
                        $free[ $rate_key ] = $rate;
                }

                return ! empty( $free ) ? array_merge( $free, $flat2 ) : $rates;
            }
```

Он скрыл все остальные способы доставки.

Этот кусок кода:

```
function alter_shipping_methods($available_gateways){
            global $woocommerce;
            $chosen_titles = array();
            $available_methods = $woocommerce->shipping->get_packages();
            $chosen_rates = ( isset( $woocommerce->session ) ) ? $woocommerce->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ) : array();
            foreach ($available_methods as $method)
            foreach ($chosen_rates as $chosen) {
            if( isset( $method['rates'][$chosen] ) ) $chosen_titles[] = $method['rates'][ $chosen ]->label;
            }
            if( in_array( 'Доставка по Москве курьером, бесплатно', $chosen_titles )||in_array( 'Доставка по Москве курьером', $chosen_titles ) || in_array( 'Доставка в регионы России, бесплатно', $chosen_titles )||in_array( 'Доставка в регионы России', $chosen_titles )) {
            unset($available_gateways['other_payment']);    

            } 

            return $available_gateways;
            }
            add_action('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'alter_shipping_methods');
```

Убирает лишний способ оплаты при выборе способов доставки.